# How can I implement a ListView without ListActivity? (use only Activity)

Tags: android, listview

I'm new to Android, and I really need to do it this way (I've considered doing it in another `Activity`), but can anyone show me a simple code (just the `onCreate()` method) that can do `Listview` without `ListActivity`?

THanks

Answer (score 55):

If you have an xml layout for the activity including a listView like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="fill_parent"
```

Then in your onCreate you could have something like this

```
setContentView(R.layout.the_view);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,int position, long id) 
     {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
});
```

Comment: How and where to you define the OnItemClick-Method?

Comment: There's no definition here for `adapter` which would be helpful

Comment: @PascalKlein from it is an override function

Comment: @Webnet `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, String items[])`

Answer (score 28):

Include the following resource in your res/layout/main.xml file:

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/id_list_view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

your_class.java

```
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class your_class extends Activity
{
  private ListView m_listview;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    m_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.id_list_view);

    String[] items = new String[] {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

    m_listview.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The following creates a simple ListView programmatically:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         String[] myList = new String[] {"Hello","World","Foo","Bar"};              
         ListView lv = new ListView(this);
         lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList));
         setContentView(lv);
}
```

Comment: Hi Cchenesson...when I follow this code, I get a "Edit Source" in my Eclipse (which means it doesn't work.) Why is that?

Comment: Weird - I created a new android prject, copy/paste the above, run it without any problems. Can you post the whole code for the activity? Where do you see that "Edit Source" in Eclipse?

Comment: Is it this problem you have? http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/

Comment: I think its for ListActivity and not for Activity

Answer (score 1):

You could also reference your layout, instantiate a layout object from your code, and then build the ListView in Java. This gives you some flexability in terms of setting dynamic height and width at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

include the following resource file in your res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <ListView
         android:id="@+id/listView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
      </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView listView;
String[] listPlanet={"mercury","Venus","Mars","Saturn","Neptune"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView));

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listPlanet);

  listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}

}
```