# Global Menu for Android Applications

Tags: android, menuitem

I am building a an Android Application. Some of my classes extends Activity and some extends ListActivity. Is there a way I can build a global menu class which can be used to generate menu.

I already know the way suggested in documentation of extending a base menu class with activity and then using that class to extend all other activities. But in my case couple of my classes extend listactivity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at TabActivity?

Comment: There is no reason you need to extend listactivity, just extend activity and give it a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Mayra says, you don't NEED to extend ListActivity to have a list in your activity. :)

Check out this other stackoverflow question that shows how to make a listview without a listactivity. [How can I implement a ListView without ListActivity? (use only Activity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242136/how-can-i-implement-a-listview-without-listactivity-use-only-activity)

:)

Answer (score 0):

create a class which extends Activity and put the oncreateoptionsmenu() function in that.

then make every other class extend this one..

similar for listactivity