# ListView without ListActivity

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to set a Listview under some other Widgets (Buttons, editText, etc). I don't want to use another activity for the listview. After reading some I found [How can I implement a ListView without ListActivity? (use only Activity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242136/how-can-i-implement-a-listview-without-listactivity-use-only-activity) and I tried to do it, ending up with:
Here is my main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView ...[some code].../>
<EditText ...[some code].../>
<ImageButton ...[some code].../>
<Chronometer ..[some code]..../>
<ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ListView>
```

here is my onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    String[] listword = new String[] {"Hello","World","Foo","Bar"};
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, listword));
    }
```

and here is list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

When I debug in my physical device, the application simply stays all black. If I comment out the lines of onCreate() that involve the list, the application works (obviously without the listview).
Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: As you suspect the widgets can't disappear without a reason. Try to set background color to the different widgets to see which one is showing.

Comment: The following show up when the listview is removed? <TextView ...[some code].../>
<EditText ...[some code].../>
<ImageButton ...[some code].../>
<Chronometer ..[some code]..../>

Comment: Yes when I removed the listview everything shows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I actually have an app with a listview below some TextViews and above two buttons, let me grab my code!

Here's my activity with listview below the textviews and above the buttons (with quite a bit removed for brevity):

```
public class BNYDirectoryResults extends Activity{

    public static String[] stuff;
    ListView list;
    BNYAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.resultscreen);

        TextView headDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);
        TextView headCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultsTotal);
        TextView headPages = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pages);

      //Set up the results list, see BNYAdapter
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new BNYAdapter (this, BNYDirectory.ReturnResults);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

      //Sets up header information (pages, total results)
        //Just some stuff to change the TextViews


      //Passes EmployeeID and Phone Number to AND opens the details page
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                String EID = BNYDirectory.ReturnResults[position][0];
                String phoneNumber = BNYDirectory.ReturnResults[position][2];

                BNYDirectoryTransaction.doDetails(EID, phoneNumber);
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), BNYDirectoryDetails.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the XML file for it:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/results"
        android:text="Name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultsTotal"
        android:text="Phone"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pages"
        android:text="AIM"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textStyle="bold"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:text="Name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:text="Phone"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aim"
        android:text="AIM"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dept"
        android:text="Dept"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prevButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Previous" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Next" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here's the custom adapter for the list:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BNYAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[][] results;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public BNYAdapter(Activity a, String[][]info) {
        activity = a;
        results = info;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return results.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView name;
        public TextView phone;
        public TextView aim;
        public TextView dept;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.name=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.nameItem);
            holder.phone=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.phoneItem);
            holder.aim=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.aimItem);
            holder.dept=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.deptItem);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        holder.name.setText(BNYDirectory.ReturnResults[position][1]);
        holder.phone.setText(BNYDirectory.ReturnResults[position][2]);
        holder.aim.setText(BNYDirectory.ReturnResults[position][3]);
        holder.dept.setText(BNYDirectory.ReturnResults[position][4]);
        return vi;
    }

}
```

and all together that makes a page like [image: Look, a list with other stuff around it!]

Comment: Thanks! I just had to put everything into another LinerLayout

Comment: Glad you got it working. I know with some of my apps I probably have too many linearlayouts.

Answer (score -2):

You can use your own layout with a ListActivity. Make your activity extend ListActivity, create your own layout and make sure that the ListView has `android:id="@android:id/list"` (this is how the ListActivity links to the ListView in your own layout), then in onCreate set your layout with `setContentView`.