# Go to the next layout when pressing the contents in a listview in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I've created a listview extending Activity (only). I want to go to the next layout when I press the contents in listview. What can I do for this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you call "to go next layout" ?

Comment: You have to learn intents and Listeners first!

Comment: Snicolas, it's not that important. What he needs is a clicklistener, and then he get put whatever he wants in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Android ListView and ListActivity - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)*  can help you to how to use the list with onitemclick.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the view for each row in your ListAdapter.  You can register a OnClickListener that will be called when the user clicks on the row.

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorite_row, null);
 view.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
     Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         beverageSelected( ((FavoriteBeverageView)view.getTag()).getFavoriteBeverage() );
     }
 });
 view.setTag( new FavoriteBeverageView( view ) );
```

Using setTag and setId can help you find the object in your list that the user selected.  Personally I think it's easiest to use setTag() adding a special object that contains the UI elements within your List row (for example titleTextView, subtitleTextView, image, etc), and add a pointer to the backing object in that special object.

In the example above the FavoriteBeverageView is that special object, and within him there is a FavoriteBeverage object that is the data that backs that list.  So in the OnClickListener can easily get the FavoriteBeverage back by just doing a ((FavoriteBeverageView)view.getTag()).getFavoriteBeverage().

Answer (score 0):

You use the [onItemClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `OnClickListener`

```
public OnClickListener myClickListener = new OnClickListener() { 
public void onClick(View v) {                 
 //code here that specifies what layout to go to.
   }
```

EDIT: I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468100/android-listview-click-howto) that may contain some more information for you.

Also, if you would like to learn about intents and loading new views you can take a look at this [tutorial](http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/opening-new-screen-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

See Stack Overflow question *[ListView without ListActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698731/listview-without-listactivity/6698819#6698819)*. There's some example code from my application that works well.