# Efficiency of Listview with the flexibility of the ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, baseadapter

I am trying to figure out the best approach for a particular UI for a particular data capture application, where I have a bunch of form widgets (EditText's and Spinner's) at the top of a vertical scrolling view, then a number of checked entries (10-200), and then a number of additional widgets at the end.

I am trying to think of the best way to get utilise the efficiency of the ListView (with the view recycling and option of the custom adapter for the checked entries), but the flexibility to include the other widgets before and after the list.

I have eliminated the idea of putting a ListView inside a Scrollview, for the well documented reasons.

I have also considered breaking it into multiple views and using the ViewFlipper, but this does not flow as well for the user experience.

The only other idea I have encountered is to put my non-listview items in as the Listview header and footer. This way I can still use my custom adapter for the listview checked entries, and the rest of the widgets are where I want.

Does this sound like the most efficient and sensible approach? Any comments and advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom listview with widgets above and below it in my app. [ListView without ListActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698731/listview-without-listactivity/6698819#6698819)

Just put the listview in it's own LinearLayout and it should work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I need to have the widgets within the scrolling view. Your solution appears to have the widgets fixed in place. Sorry if I have misunderstood.