# Android Forced Close on the Google Maps

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am trying to show `Google Map` on the `Top Half` of the Android Screen, And in the `Bottom Half` I am trying to create `List View dynamically`.

**Problem Statement:-**

But whenever I try to run this below program, my application always gets `forced closed.`

And the exception that I always get is-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testproject/com.example.testproject.MyTwoListItemsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
```

Below is my code-

```
public class MyTwoListItemsActivity extends ListActivity {
private ListView mListView;
private MapView mapView;
private MapController mapController;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(15);

    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = buildData();
    String[] from = { "name", "purpose" };
    int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> buildData() {
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    list.add(putData("Android", "Mobile"));
    list.add(putData("Windows7", "Windows7"));
    list.add(putData("iPhone", "iPhone"));
    return list;
}

private HashMap<String, String> putData(String name, String purpose) {
    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item.put("name", name);
    item.put("purpose", purpose);
    return item;
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

And this is my XML file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:apiKey="0s_fADEBtq0-j_teQ1j-yaoDAivoHHtwN81rJ-g"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:state_enabled="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mylist"
            android:layout_width="164dp"
            android:layout_height="142dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google MapView always require the use of MapActivity. You can use a ListView without a ListActivity to achieve your goal of a list with a map.

Edit:

See SO question: [ListView without ListActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698731/listview-without-listactivity)

Comment: Thanks Morrison, Can you show me an example how can I achieve the same without ListActivity.

Answer (score 0):

So Android has this rule which basically goes like this:

```
MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity
```

I'm sure something like this must be printed in your logcat error messages.

What this simply means is that due to Java's lack of support for multiple inheritance you can't extend two different Activities.