# TextView and ListView in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, listview

I searched for similar questions but didn't get the proper answer, so posting it as a new question.

Can a `LinearLayout` have two `TextViews` and one list view? I learn that listview can be used to display array elements only if the class extends `ListActivity`. The Class in my app extends Activity and uses listView.

I am trying to build an RSS Reader based on [IBM tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-androidrss/index.html). On running the project I am getting parsed text in both the Text views but `ListView` is not displaying. I can post the code and Logcat if required.

Comment: post the code, that will make things better

Answer (score 3):

Linear Layout can have any number of children.
ListActivity is an Activity that Android have added for convenience when dealing with activities comprised of list.

You can use ListView on a regular Activity and just implement an adapter that will populate the list items with data from your model.

Android has some ready-made adapters that can be used for simple use-cases.
of course if you need a more complicated beahviour you can extend them.

Have a look on [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html), [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) and [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) to get a better understanding of how to use adapters.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `ListView` in any activity, using a `ListActivity` just makes your life easier (usually). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242136/how-can-i-implement-a-listview-without-listactivity-use-only-activity) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Linear layout with different views and list view inside for example:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/background_new_search_activity_1">

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_amount_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And yes you can use the `ListView`in all the activities, it is not necessary to extend `ListActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the orientation of the `ListView` is set to vertical. Otherwise, it will try to display all items side by side, and those that fall outside the available view area won't be visible.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">    <!-- << orientation setting here -->
```