# How to load list of items from Array into ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

i am trying to load the list of items from arrays... i get runtime error

**02-22 11:22:51.042: E/AndroidRuntime(1460): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'**

my R.java file

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
        public static final int icon=0x7f020001;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int mylist=0x7f050000;
        public static final int next=0x7f050005;
        public static final int play=0x7f050004;
        public static final int prev=0x7f050003;
        public static final int seekbar=0x7f050002;
        public static final int selectedfile=0x7f050001;
        public static final int text1=0x7f050006;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int audiolist=0x7f030000;
        public static final int song_item=0x7f030001;
        public static final int songlist=0x7f030002;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;
    }
}
```

my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
      setContentView(R.layout.audiolist);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
listView.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

layout: audiolist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light"
        android:padding="10dip">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/selectedfile"
            android:text="Not file selected"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="middle"/>

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:max="100"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/prev"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should look at that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040374/runtime-exception-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)

You ll either have to change the `listview'`s id to that default or you need to use `setContentView(...)`

**Update:**  Code sample

You can check [the tutorial of Vogella](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html), it s a great one showing u step by step. You cannot fail.

**Update 2** Possible solution
My last guess is that your activity extends `ListActivity` so the builder is looking for a default list as the layout. IF so, use simple Activity instead and see the answer to this question: [How can I implement a ListView without ListActivity? (use only Activity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242136/how-can-i-implement-a-listview-without-listactivity-use-only-activity)

Good luck

Comment: in your reference its populating the ListView from Contacts but i have my own Array that i want to populate from, as i have in my above code... any help?

Comment: 1) no it doesnT list from contacts. 2) where ure filling from is irrelevant. But i see u are confused so i ll update my code. If you want more answers, I suggest u update your question with the latest state of XML and code.

Comment: Thanks Zortkun, yes i think i am lost :),.....so let me ask you before i jump into the notepad tutorial,.... in order to fix my code what correction do i need? i want to start with very simple like what i am trying to do is to just load arraylist in my listview but not sure what is causing to crash my app...

Answer (score -1):

When you are extending ListActivity and creating listView, id of ListView should be just "list" not mylist.

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
```

Comment: i changed to `list` but still getting the error: 02-22 ` E/AndroidRuntime(1530): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' `

Comment: Should be android.R.id.list not your.package.R.id.list ... So this answer is wrong .. Read first comment this is good one

Comment: @Selvin: i tried `ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);` still get the same error