# How to display rows extracted from sqlite table in listview or any similar view

Tags: android

[image: *for example [image is attached]**]

sample values are colomn1, colomn2.
After fetching values I should display them row by row.
Please help me here.

[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT3kx.png)

```
 public ArrayList<String> getAllData(){
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    //hp=new HashMap();
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res=db.rawQuery("select * from spendlist", null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    if (res != null && res.moveToFirst() ){
        while (!res.isAfterLast()) {
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(SPEND_LIST_COLUMN_DESC)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

above code i am using to fetch data to populate it i am using

```
 ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllData();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

    obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Now I want to fetch all data instead one column and populate it

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, so unfortunately I can only give a very broad answer. A [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) might be the simplest way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is ListView, a custom layout for each item list and an ArrayAdapter.
You can check [this answer for inspiration.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242136/how-can-i-implement-a-listview-without-listactivity-use-only-activity)

Comment: hi, I am using ArrayAdpter but to display one value. [code attached above]

now I want to display 2 values.